# Customize opt-in Activation Link

Tags: kentico

Is there any way to customize opt in approval link?
Tricks like this  won't work:
`{% ActivationLink %}specialID={%  %}` 
I would like to pass some additional parameters to Activation page. I am using Kentico 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with this macro ?

```
{% ActivationUrl %}
```

This macro is present in the email, but it isn't visible in the editor in admin UI

Comment: Perfect, this works like a charm.
`<a href="{% ActivationUrl %}&amp;user_email={% Email %}&amp;newsletter_id={% Newsletter.ID #%}">Activation link</a>` .

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this does not seem possible without access to the source code. The link itself is hardcoded in DLL in an internal method and it contains only preselected parameters such as activationPage, SubscriptionApprovalHash and dateTime. This string is converted to link and covered with resource string Newsletter.ActivationLink.

There is no easy workaround and it could be better to pass additional data via some other method or somewhere else in the email itself.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming Custom Macro's might not work here? 
Can you do something on the Activation page and use the referrer?

Comment: Does not sound like an answer, or?